# Why "Write-Host" works differently from PowerShell function and timer handler?

Tags: powershell

I have 1809 Windows 10 box with PowerShell Core 6.1.1
Given following code sample:

```
function Test() {
  Write-Host "Test"
}
function Invoke-Test() {
  $timer = New-Object System.Timers.Timer
  $timer.AutoReset = $false
  $timer.Interval = 1
  Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName Elapsed -Action {
    Test
  }
  $timer.Enabled = $true
}
```

If I invoke "Test" function, I get "Test" output as expected:

[image]

But if I schedule invocation with a timer, command prompt is completely messed up:

[image]

I vaguely understand that it's something related to internal "readline" and console mechanic, but is it any way to produce newline output followed by a command prompt from a timer/handle in powershell?

Comment: I am familiar with this issue. Interestingly, I just tried it with PowerShell v5.1.17134.407 and it does output the prompt. Apparently this behavior was changed in the newest release? Worth investigating. Not sure about pwsh core of course.

Answer (score -2):

```
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName Elapsed -SourceIdentifier Timer.Test -Action {
    Test
  }

$timer.Enabled = $true

PS C:\> $Subscriber = Get-EventSubscriber -SourceIdentifier Timer.Test
PS C:\> $Subscriber.action | Format-List -Property *
```

The command property should hold the results of your “test” function.

The url below has detailed explanations.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-eventsubscriber?view=powershell-6